# Let $G$ be a graph with $2n+1$ vertices and more than $nΔ(G)$ edges. Prove that the chromatic index $χ' = Δ(G) + 1$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

By Vising's theorem: $Δ(G) \leq χ' \leq Δ(G) + 1$. It's enough to prove that $χ' > Δ(G)$.
Since there are more than $nΔ(G)$ edges, using the handshaking lemma, the sum of the degrees of all vertices is at least $2nΔ(G)$. The sum of degrees is bounded by an upper bound: $C^2_{2n} = 2n^2 + n$. This means that $2nΔ(G) \leq 2n^2 + n$, so $Δ(G) < n$. I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume Vizing's theorem, we can solve this using a counting argument.

Hint: Show we can have at most $n$ edges with the same colour.

This can be done by contradiction.

> Assume we have $k\geq n+1$ edges of the same colour, they must be adjacent to $2k \geq 2n+2$ distinct vertices (but we only have $2n+1$). Therefore, we can have at most $n$ edges with the same colour.

> We are given that we have $|E|>n\Delta(G)$ edges, and therefore we need at least $\frac{|E|}{n} > \Delta(G)$ colours. Vizing's theorem tells us the chromatic index must be $\Delta()+1$.